# Python Selenium Geckodriver Connection refused

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb, geckodriver

I spent hours trying to make Selenium works with Python no luck
this error message 
`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused`
this is the example I have used:-

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.python.org')
browser.close()
```

This is depence I intalled 
`apt-get install -y xorg xvfb  dbus-x11 xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic`

This is  `/root/geckodriver.log` output

> 1493938773101   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:40876
>   1493938774156   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser
>   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh with args ["-marionette"] (firefox:3128):
>   GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count >
>   0' failed

I'm running Selenium on `Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit` VPS remote server with 128MB RAM
I can't figure out what's make Selenium not able to communicate with browsers drivers both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I gave up on `Geckodriver` and I use `PhantomJS` as my webdriver.

```
 from selenium import webdriver  
 display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
 display.start() 
 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
 driver.get('http://www.python.org')
 html_source = driver.page_source
 print ("html_source:",html_source) 
 driver.quit()
```

Here are the steps I used to install PhantomJS :

```
cd ~
export PHANTOM_JS="phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64"
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share
ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin



Python  Selenium        
apt-get install python-pip  -y 
pip uninstall pyvirtualdisplay
apt-get install x11vnc xvfb fluxbox
Xvfb :99 -ac
xvfb-run  -a   python 99.py
pip uninstall selenium
pip install selenium==2.53.1
```

See also [How to install PhantomJS on Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620).

Comment: Thanks. I too was frustrated with Selenium+Firefox+Geckodriver's endless problems, and PhantomJS just works.

Answer (score 4):

Please start with checking your "firefox" browser version.

I found it very confusing at some point. I'm using the Raspbian and the "Iceweasel" downloaded with apt-get was a Firefox 52 version which didn't work with geckodriver 0.19 (this one requires Firefox 55 or greater).

What worked for me was to download geckorvider v0.16 and that resolved the problem.

Whats moreover, you probably don't need xorg to make it work, the only packages I needed was xfvb and iceweasel.

Comment: I tried multiple versions but none of them works , because both Firefox and chrome drivers confused with server with no graphic output . PhantomJS do all my requirement and works like real browser .

Comment: xvfb should be enough to deal with that, maybe those problems have their roots in some dependencies you have installed?
Do you have a chance to test it on a "clean" account with just xvfb and selenium installed?